# React can't fetch data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to fetch data from given API (link is censored in code example), but can't manage to to display `product.name` from my API fetch.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function DataFetching() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://CENSORED/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setPosts(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <h1>{post.product.name}</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Errors [image]

Comment: your res.data seems to be an object - not an array. which is why it complains that you are trying to call a array function on a object.

Comment: Im not sure if what you are fetching is supposed to be a single post, or multiple posts..but here is an example of how to fetch and handle data. this data is received as an array: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYUwLgxgFgFARFMYAOBnAXAekwQ2QSwDowoQIcw8iIB7AW0wDcBGTAIwCcQQATVOAJTFSAOxhdUAAgC8APkkTCAK1Q0xAoSRBiJM+bRGqANiEJGaAc3EhUGoA

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the posts array is empty initially you need to check first if the array has some data then perform a map

```
setPosts(res.data.product)
```

```
{posts?.map((post) => (
   <h1>{post.name}</h1>
))}
```

or you can use conditional like this

```
{ posts.length > 0 
 ? posts.map((post) => (
   <h1>{post.name}</h1>
))
 : <Your custom message/>
}
```

Comment: after i used the conditional code you provided it just displays the else part of the code. Why is that so? How could that array be empty?

Comment: @Kikoanno you need to add posts variable in the use effect dependency array also

Comment: `useEffect(() => { }, [posts]);` like this

Comment: @dean by making this API call i should fetch data as from an object? or i need to change the object to an array?

Comment: @Kikoanno in your case it's array of objects

Comment: @Kikoanno this will fix your issue `setPosts(res.data.product)`

Comment: @Kikoanno and access data like this `{post.name}`

Comment: and that product key must be an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

`res.data` is indicated to be an object in the `console.log`. the `map` method will only work on arrays. If you were expecting an array, make sure you aren't hitting the "detail" endpoint, which would return specific information about a post.